# Select 1px aliased border

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I choose Select > Modify > Border and select a 1px border - the border I get is anti-aliased, hence if I fill my selection a 3px border is affected.

Is there a way to select a 1px aliased border?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going your route and 'painting' the border, why not try layer styles > stroke (outside 1px)?

This should give you a clean 1px border with no alias. Also you can always go back and change its colour/size etc any time you need.

You can access layer styles from the bottom of the layes panel (FX) > Stroke.

Or similar to your approach, you can try edit > stroke (1px) this will 'paint' the border without anti-aliased.

Comment: Thx for helping out, Hasan :)

I don't want a uniform stroke so I need to paint a selection.

My "Edit > stroke" is greyed out.

Comment: FX has Gradient stroke (non-uniform) as well by the way. 

Try select the area with marquee (M) or (w) then Edit>Stroke should become available. Or make sure your layer is not locked. 

Though you can only do solid line with this!

Comment: have another idea! you can manually draw a selection (M or L) around your shape and paint! Its not very straight forward but it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do.....

1. Select all
2. Zoom in and use the Single Row or Single Column Marque tool. Hold
   down Option/Alt and select one row along all 4 edges.
3. Invert Selection (Select > Inverse)

That will give you a 1 pixel border without anti-aliasing.The Option/Alt key will subtract from the Select All, then you merely invert to get the 1 pixel edge.

Of course, you could also simply zoom in, use the Single Column/Single Row Marquee tools holding Shift to ad to the selection and just select the edge pixels.

Unfortunately the "Border" command always anti-aliases giving you 2 or 3 pixels at a minimum.